# PHP Switch statement error

Tags: php

```
 <?php
 include 'db.php';
 $mail=$_SESSION['session_u_e_mail'];
if(!isset($_GET['edit']))
{
$_GET['edit']=0;
}
switch($_GET['edit'])
{
 case 1: echo "Value";
         break;

 case 2: echo "Value";
         break;

 default: echo "Value";
         break;

 }
```

I m facing problem that the values in every case is echoed twice.

Comment: Are you certain the problem comes from those lines and not something after that?

Comment: @user855360: [No, it doesn't](http://codepad.org/NjCn5j33). Make a testcase that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in this code that would even output your default value. No matter the input, this outputs `Value`. Look in `db.php` or the files included by it for debugging `echo`es.

Answer (score 2):

I've just grabbed the

```
if(!isset($_GET['edit']))
{
$_GET['edit']=0;
}
switch($_GET['edit'])
{
 case 1: echo "Value";
         break;

 case 2: echo "Value";
         break;

 default: echo "Value";
         break;

 }
```

this portion and pasted onto codepad and it works fine.

Here is the working version: http://codepad.org/P8bhL5vl

It outputs just "Value".

Comment: Probably your code going bad in your `db.php` file. Check that out and you will find the problem.